# NHibernate, Left outer join

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

How can I create nhibernate query, that should look like the below sql query

```
select * from A
left outer join B on A.ID = B.ID
left outer join C on B.ProdID = C.ProdID
```

Unfortunately, I can't use the named query. 
And what the mapping of A should look like?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NHibernate Left Outer Join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756148/nhibernate-left-outer-join)

Comment: There is a niffty tool called [NHibernate Mapping Generator](http://nmg.codeplex.com/).  It can help you get use to the syntax of the XML, fluent, and ByCode mapping styles.

Comment: Please, add your current mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Map B as a many-to-one property of A. The B to C relation doesn't seem to be a normal foreign key and can't be mapped as a property. So it can't be left outer joined.

HQL, C can't be left outer joined:

```
select *
from A a 
  left join a.B b,
  C c
where
  c.Description = b.Description
```

Comment: Sorry, for bad explanation of problem, I did some edit, ProdId is foreign key of table B.

Comment: Why not? It is very powerful.